# Proof that the sup of a set is the least upper bound.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have to prove: Assume $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Then, $s = \text{sup}A$ if and only if, for every choice of $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $s - \varepsilon < a$.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Take $s=\text{sup}A$. Consider $s-\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon>0$. Since $s-\varepsilon<s$, we see that $s-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A$. So, there exists some $a\in A$ with $s-\varepsilon<a$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ We show $s$ is the least upper bound. Take $v$ to be an upper bound of $A$. We assume for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $a\in A$ with $s-\varepsilon<a$. Since $v$ is an upper bound of $A$, we have $s-\varepsilon<a\leq v$. In particular, $s-\varepsilon<v$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.

I don't know how to end the second part of the proof. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If $v > s-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$, you must have $v \ge s$.

If $v<s$, take $\epsilon = {1 \over 2} (s-v)$, then $s-\epsilon = v+ \epsilon > v$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why did you establish a contradiction? In particular, why doesn't it suffice to stop at $v\geq s$?

Comment: Ah I see, the inequality is not obvious, it needs to be proved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Moz: I can't think of a 'constructive' proof.

Comment: Looking over my proof, I neglected to show, in the reverse direction, that $s$ is an upper bound.

Comment: Never mind, it was part of the assumption.

Comment: Could I have used, instead of $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}(s-v)$, $\varepsilon=s-v$. This would simply leave $v>v$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I was just being safe :-).